# Regarding Hahn Banach theorem and supporting hyperplane

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

[image]

In the above image from the book Linear Analysis by Bela Bollobas, corollary 7 gives the first consequence to the Hahn Banach Theorem. In the paragraph below corollary 8 they define a supporting functional and support plane. For a linear functional $f$ on a Banach space $X$ $$ I(f)=\{x\in X: f(x)=1\},$$ and $B(X)$  is the closed unit ball in $X$. The second last line of the bottomost paragraph states that $I(f)$ contains no interior point of $B(X)$. Can anyone tell why?

Comment: What is $S(X)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I(f)$ contains some open ball $B(x,r)$ then $y \in B(0,r)$ implies $f(y+x)=1$ so $f(y)=1-f(x)$. In particular this must hold for $y=0$ so $1-f(x)=0$ which in turn  gives $f(y)=0$ for all $y \in B(0,r)$. But then $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: Here $I(f)$ is a subspace of hyperplane.  What would you mean by $I(f)$ containing $B(x,r)$? Like in three dimensional space, $B(x,r)$ would be an open sphere with center $x$ and $I(f)$ would be a plane.

Comment: Yes. if  a set has an interior point $x$ then there would be some $r>0$ such that the set contains the open ball $B(x,r)$.

Comment: So going by your proof, if we consider $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $B(0,r)$ will be a open unit disc centered at $0$, so how will $f$ being zero at $B(0,r)$ imply that $f$ is the zero function?